# How to use Gatsby templates within a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, contentful

I am in the process of redesigning my site...it's turning into a single page design. My [pervious site](https://mrpbennett.com/) I am publishing my posts dynamically via my `gastby-node` file. As well as having a template file for my actual post and my list of posts.

I have tried to insert my `post-list` template into my `main` component which acts as my font page. I am getting undefined errors with my variables though. For example I get `currentPage` is undefined.

#### My Post List template...

```
import React from "react"
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"
import { IconContext } from "react-icons"
import { GoChevronLeft, GoChevronRight } from "react-icons/go"

export const query = graphql`
  query($skip: Int!, $limit: Int!) {
    allContentfulPosts(
      sort: { fields: publishedDate, order: DESC }
      limit: $limit
      skip: $skip
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          postTitle
          slug
          publishedDate(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

const PostList = props => {
  const { currentPage, postNumPages } = props.pageContext
  const isFirst = currentPage === 1
  const isLast = currentPage === postNumPages
  const prevPage =
    currentPage - 1 === 1 ? "posts/" : "posts/" + (currentPage - 1).toString()
  const nextPage = "posts/" + (currentPage + 1).toString()

  const posts = props.data.allContentfulPosts.edges

  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map(({ node }) => {
        const title = node.postTitle || node.slug
        return (
          <div className="">
            <div className="mb-4">
              <Link to={`/posts/${node.slug}`}>
                <h2 className="text-gray-800 underline font-sans font-black hover:text-gray-500 text-lg mb-2 sm:text-xl md:text-2xl">
                  {title}
                </h2>
              </Link>
              <span className="text-gray-500">
                Posted on {node.publishedDate}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      })}

      <div className="bg-white px-4 py-3 flex items-center justify-between mb-4">
        <div className="">
          {!isFirst && (
            <Link to={prevPage} rel="prev">
              <IconContext.Provider
                value={{
                  className: "h-6 w-6 text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-500",
                }}
              >
                <GoChevronLeft />
              </IconContext.Provider>
            </Link>
          )}
        </div>

        <div className="flex font-sans">
          {Array.from({ length: postNumPages }, (_, i) => (
            <Link
              className="mx-2 border border-gray-500 py-2 px-4 text-gray-900 shadow hover:bg-blue-300 hover:text-white hover:no-underline rounded-full"
              activeClassName="bg-blue-300 text-white font-black"
              key={`pagination-number${i + 1}`}
              to={`posts/${i === 0 ? "" : i + 1}`}
            >
              {i + 1}
            </Link>
          ))}
        </div>

        <div className="">
          {!isLast && (
            <Link to={nextPage} rel="next">
              <IconContext.Provider
                value={{
                  className: "h-6 w-6 text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-500",
                }}
              >
                <GoChevronRight />
              </IconContext.Provider>
            </Link>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default PostList
```

#### My Post template

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import { TwitterShareButton } from "react-twitter-embed"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"

export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    contentfulPosts(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      postTitle
      publishedDate(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
      postBodyMd {
        childMarkdownRemark {
          html
          timeToRead
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

const Post = props => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title={props.data.contentfulPosts.postTitle} />

      <div className="w-full">
        <div className="">
          <h1 className="font-black mb-2 text-2xl lg:text-4xl">
            {props.data.contentfulPosts.postTitle}
          </h1>
          <p className="text-gray-500 font-mono">
            {props.data.contentfulPosts.publishedDate} ·{" "}
            {
              props.data.contentfulPosts.postBodyMd.childMarkdownRemark
                .timeToRead
            }{" "}
            min read
          </p>

          <TwitterShareButton
            options={{
              text: `NewPost: ${props.data.contentfulPosts.postTitle}. #developer #programming - `,
              via: "mrpbennett",
              size: "large",
            }}
            placeholder="Loading"
          />
        </div>

        <div
          className="text-base sm:text-xl"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html:
              props.data.contentfulPosts.postBodyMd.childMarkdownRemark.html,
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Post
```

#### My gatsby-node file

```
const path = require("path")
const { createFilePath } = require("gatsby-source-filesystem")

// DYNAMICALLY CREATE PAGES FOR EACH POST
module.exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const postTemplate = path.resolve("src/templates/post.js")
  const postResult = await graphql(`
    query {
      allContentfulPosts {
        edges {
          node {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  // Handle errors
  if (postResult.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild("Error while running GraphQL query.")
    return
  }

  // Create the pages for each markdown file
  postResult.data.allContentfulPosts.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      component: postTemplate,
      path: `/posts/${node.slug}`,
      context: {
        slug: node.slug,
      },
    })
  })

  // PAGINATION FOR BLOG POSTS
  const postsResult = await graphql(`
    {
      allContentfulPosts(
        sort: { fields: publishedDate, order: DESC }
        limit: 1000
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  if (postsResult.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild("Error while running GraphQL query.")
    return
  }

  // Create blog-list pages
  const posts = postsResult.data.allContentfulPosts.edges
  const postsPerPage = 6
  const postNumPages = Math.ceil(posts.length / postsPerPage)
  Array.from({ length: postNumPages }).forEach((_, i) => {
    createPage({
      path: i === 0 ? "/posts" : `/posts/${i + 1}`,
      component: path.resolve("./src/templates/post-list.js"),
      context: {
        limit: postsPerPage,
        skip: i * postsPerPage,
        postNumPages,
        currentPage: i + 1,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

Now if I go to the url domain.com/posts/blogtitle for example. I get my post coming in from content. So i know it works to a certain extent. But how can i get the post list to display within a standard component.

Comment: If you mean to get the post list in a normal component (not a page component), just call the correct API like you did in your `PostList` component, but use another library like `Apollo-client` or `SWR` to fetch data.

Comment: so instead of `import { graphql } from "gatsby"` using something from apollo etc?

Comment: Correct, `graphql` from `gatsby` is only used for `staticQuery`.

Comment: got any good tutorials on how to implement it with gatsby I am having issues